# Replace duplicate values from one DF to another DF

Tags: python, pandas

df1

```
ITEM      CATEGORY       COLOR

48684      CAR           RED
54519      BIKE          BLACK
14582      CAR           BLACK
45685      JEEP          WHITE
23661      BIKE          BLUE
23226      BIKE          BLUE
54252      BIKE          BLACK
```

df2

```
    USERID  WEBBROWSE   ITEM     PURCHASE
1   1541    CHROME      54252    YES
2   3351    EXPLORER    54519    YES
3   2639    MOBILE APP  23661    YES
```

df2 has many other columns.

The output I need is:

```
    USERID  WEBBROWSE   ITEM     PURCHASE
1   1541    CHROME      54519    YES
2   3351    EXPLORER    54519    YES
3   2639    MOBILE APP  23661    YES
```

From df1 it is clear that `ITEM` `54252` and `54519` are the same. So based on df1 we need to replace the values in df2.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modify previous solution with new column `orig` for remember original values of `ITEM`, create Series by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) values in another DataFrame:

```
df = df1.assign(orig=df1['ITEM'])
m = df.duplicated(['CATEGORY', 'COLOR'], keep=False)
df.loc[m, 'ITEM'] = df[m].groupby(['CATEGORY', 'COLOR'])['ITEM'].transform('first')

s = df[m].set_index('orig')['ITEM']
print (s)
orig
54519    54519
23661    23661
23226    23661
54252    54519
Name: ITEM, dtype: int64

df2['ITEM'] = df2['ITEM'].replace(s)
print (df2)
   USERID   WEBBROWSE   ITEM PURCHASE
1    1541      CHROME  54519      YES
2    3351    EXPLORER  54519      YES
3    2639  MOBILE APP  23661      YES
```

Another alternative without new column is replace by dictionary:

```
orig = df1['ITEM']
m = df1.duplicated(['CATEGORY', 'COLOR'], keep=False)
df1.loc[m, 'ITEM'] = df1[m].groupby(['CATEGORY', 'COLOR'])['ITEM'].transform('first')
print (df1)
    ITEM CATEGORY  COLOR
0  48684      CAR    RED
1  54519     BIKE  BLACK
2  14582      CAR  BLACK
3  45685     JEEP  WHITE
4  23661     BIKE   BLUE
5  23661     BIKE   BLUE
6  54519     BIKE  BLACK

d = dict(zip(orig[m], df1.loc[m, 'ITEM']))
print (d)
{54519: 54519, 23661: 23661}

df2['ITEM'] = df2['ITEM'].replace(d)
print (df2)
   USERID   WEBBROWSE   ITEM PURCHASE
1    1541      CHROME  54252      YES
2    3351    EXPLORER  54519      YES
3    2639  MOBILE APP  23661      YES
```